# Visual Studio 2010 backup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, backup

I have visual studio 2010 professional edition and I want to backup all my projects so I could transfer them onto a different computer is there any way I can do that.

Comment: Just transfer the project folders to an external storage device.

Answer (score 0):

If there are many projects - You could easily move all of your projects into one folder and then zip the folder so that it doesn't take up too much space (also helps the moving process to become quicker).

To zip you could use applications such as winRAR which will be helpful to you.

Ofcourse you will need to then unzip this folder on the other pc.

You are probably thinking into it way too much, it is literally a case of copy and paste, no strings attached.